# Flexbox scroll overflowing content in an dynamic sized parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a simple `menu` and `content` div structure. The `menu` has no fixed size and can expand depending on its content. The `content` div underneath should take the available space and scroll its own content if overflowing. Unfortunately, `flexbox` now behaves in such a way that the `content` div, due to its `flex:1` property, expands according to its content instead of scrolling the content.

Is there a way to preserve the dynamic sizes using `flex:1` and also have the content of the `content` div scroll?

```js
    function toggleMenu() {
      const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      if(menu.classList.contains("open")) {
        menu.querySelector(".text").innerHTML = "<p> small text </p>";
        menu.classList.remove("open");
      }else {
        menu.querySelector(".text").innerHTML = "<h1> im the menu </h1>";
        menu.classList.add("open");
      }
    }
```

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #17141d;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: grey;
    }

    .menu {
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }

    .content {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: aqua;
    }

    .segment-wrapper {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      background-color: red;
      flex-direction: column;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .segment {
      height: 500px;
      background-color: green;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="menu open">
      <div class="text"><h1>im the menu</h1></div>
      <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="segment-wrapper">
        <div class="segment">

        </div>
        <div class="segment">

        </div>
        <div class="segment">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing

1. an height on `.main` to size it according to body or the viewport's height.
2. overflow on `.content`, so it overflows, unless you want `.main` to overflow (which body does already)
3. and finally flex-shrink:0; on `.segment` so it doesn't shrink :)

here an example of what i understood you were after:

```js
function toggleMenu() {
      const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      if(menu.classList.contains("open")) {
        menu.querySelector(".text").innerHTML = "<p> small text </p>";
        menu.classList.remove("open");
      }else {
        menu.querySelector(".text").innerHTML = "<h1> im the menu </h1>";
        menu.classList.add("open");
      }
    }
```

```css
body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #17141d;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: grey;
      max-height;100%;
    }

    .menu {
      background-color: blueviolet;
    }

    .content {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      background-color: aqua;
      overflow:auto;
    }

    .segment-wrapper {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      background-color: red;
      flex-direction: column;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .segment {
    flex-shrink:0;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: green;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu open">
      <div class="text"><h1>im the menu</h1></div>
      <button onclick="toggleMenu()">Toggle</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="segment-wrapper">
        <div class="segment">

        </div>
        <div class="segment">

        </div>
        <div class="segment">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What would be the solution if I want to have the overflow only on the x axis?

Comment: @KreutzerCode do you mean to have them all side by side instead a column ? if so , remove the `flex-direction` and reset `overflow-y` to `overflow`, cause it might happens that it also need to overflow on y ... .